# VB.NET - How To Make a Post to Blogspot Using Blogger API V3?

Tags: vb.net, api, google-api, blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to to make a new post through my vb.net application using [blogger api](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost).
But I'm fail every time.
Sometimes it's return 403 forbidden error some times Unauthorised error.
Please Help.

```
 Dim mBlogID As String = "5861877551002158183"
    Dim AuthToken As String = "AIza......xxxx..........E6g"
    Dim post As String = "{""kind"": ""blogger#post"", ""blog"": { ""id"": """ & mBlogID & """}, ""title"": ""abc-title"", ""content"": ""abc-cont""}"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/" & mBlogID & "/posts?key=" & AuthToken), HttpWebRequest)


    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = post.Length
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization: ", AuthToken) '<--- error here

    Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        Dim postBuffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post)
        requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length)
    End Using


    Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) '<--- Unauthorised error or 403 error here
        Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using responseReader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                'Dim json As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
                'Dim PostURL As String = Regex.Match(json, """url"": ?""(?<id>.+)""").Groups("id").Value
                MsgBox(json) 'want to read json response here.
                'MsgBox(PostURL)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

This code return this error :Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
Parameter name: name

can anybody fix it? I just want to make a new post to [blogger](http://www.blogger.com) and read its URL.

Project Information:-

Platform: Visual Basic 2010

Blogger API Version: V3

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest view [this solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amit12345/accessing-google-blogger-api-from-net/). The post has fully explanations.

Comment: At the time of your answer, this question has become 10 months old question. Currently I'm working on another project and will look your solution latter. Thanks.